# Git worktree vs. Git branches: is it worth upgrading for?

Tags: git, github

I need to set up a development environment for an internal application. Both the development branch and the "master" branch will be housed on the same internal server, and GitHub will host the remote repositories.

I started researching, and it seems that `git worktree` might be a good solution for this. It will allow us to use separate branches for deployed code and development code without requiring much overhead and will make it more likely that we won't have any accidental merges into the wrong branch.

The issue is that our server is currently on Git version 1.7, while the `worktree` feature was released in version 2.5.

THE QUESTION: would having `worktree` functionality be worth the time it would take to upgrade Git on our server compared to whatever alternate solution we would need to deploy if we were to stay on version 1.7? If we were to stay on version 1.7, what would be our best option for having two separate branches of code on the same server that must be synced when changes are approved?

Comment: Sorry this is sort of a sideways answer to your question: You should always be able to upgrade Git to the latest version without any disruption to your workflows. In other words, it's always a good idea to upgrade Git to the latest version, even without your worktree issue.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear - worktree isn't an alternative to branches.  It's just a way of checking out multiple branches simultaneously.  I'm not sure how this would address the problem of "accidental merges into the wrong branch"?  (At least not compared to the traditional approach of multiple clones or whatever.)

Comment: For what it's worth, even on CentOS (the only system I know that still comes with a Git that ancient) installing a modern Git should just be a matter of cloning, building, and installing.